# Let $\sigma_{k}(n) = \sum_{d|n}d^{k}$ then $\sigma_{k}$ is multiplicative.

Tags: number-theory

I’m currently taking my first number theory module and am confused regarding a question on the first assignment:

> Let $\sigma_{k}(n) = \sum_{d|n}d^{k}$
> then $\sigma_{k}$ is multiplicative.

How should I begin? My lecturer has not been helpful and her notes incomplete...

Comment: Begin by letting $k=1$ and $n=p^aq^b$ where $p$ and $q$ are primes.

Comment: If $f$ is multiplicative, then so is $g$ as defined by $g(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)$.

Comment: Thank you so much... I will try this out :)

Comment: Showing that $\sigma_k(mn) = \sigma_k(m) \sigma_k(n), gcd(n,m)=1$ is not hard. Also what are the Dirichlet series and Euler products of $n^k$ and $\sigma_k(n)$ ?

Comment: Do not vandalize your own question.

Answer (score 2):

The arithmetic functions $\sigma_k$ are multiplicative, because they are the Dirichlet product of two multiplicative functions, namely of the function $f(d)=d^k$ and the function function $u(n)=1$ for all $n$, i.e.,
$$
\sigma^k=u\ast f.
$$

**Theorem** Let $f,g$ be two multiplicative functions. Then their Dirichlet product $f\ast g$ is multiplicative.

Proof: Apostol, Introduction to Analytic Number Theory, Chapter $2$.

Comment: I don't think it is fair to complain about the lecturer and the lecture notes. There are several ways to prove this, but this is how many number theory texts do it. You can also follow another book if the lecture notes are incomplete.